# Check if value of dataframe is existing in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to **split a pandas Dataframe into two, based on the value in the column "country"**.

If the value exists in the following list (EU-COUNTRY-CODES), the row should be added to a dataframe called "EU", if it does not exist in the list I want to add the row to another dataframe.

```
eu-country-codes = ["BE","BG","DK","EE","FI","FR","GR","IE","IT","HR","LV","LT","LU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SM","SE","SK","SI","ES","CZ","HU","VA","FO","CY"]
```

I tried to do it this way but got following Error:

```
data = pd.read_csv("datei.csv", sep=",", header=0)
eu= data[data["country"] not in eu-country-codes]

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `eu = data[~data["country"].isin(eu-country-codes)]` I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
data[data["country"].isin( eu-country-codes)==False]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I love those problems where is waste my lifetime thanks to less than 10 letters.